# What does it mean to “join the chord AB”?

Tags: geometry, terminology

I have a question that is rather simple, but i’d like some clarification regarding the matter as I will eventually need to explain it to my students.

I was reading a proof regarding the inequality concerning x, sin x and tan x.

I understand the majority of the proof except where it says "join the chord AB".

Now, if a chord is defined to be the line segment that joins the endpoints A and B (where endpoints are on the circumference of circle), why is the word 'join' used in the above statement? I believe there is a better choice of word, such as construct. Can someone confirm whether or not I am misunderstanding what is trying to be conveyed.

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

Thank you for the suggested edit. The author has used it multiple times throughout the textbook and I have also seen the same terminology in a different paper which makes me believe I am missing something.

For the second paper I am referring to, please see the proof on page 9, in the link below.

https://amsi.org.au/teacher_modules/pdfs/Circle_Geometry.pdf

[screenshot of proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvYPS.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Please provide more context for the phrase in question. What is the full sentence (or paragraph) in which it appears? (Can you provide a screenshot of, or link to, the complete proof?) Does the author use "join" elsewhere in a (dis)similar manner? Could this be a translation issue? (Add any context and clarification to the body of the question itself. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Context seems to suggest that "join" simply means "draw" or (as you note) "construct". The phrasing "join chord $XY$" rings a *little* odd to my (American) ear, but I think I could get used to it. (That doesn't make it *worse* than whatever I might typically use.) Perhaps it's a cultural idiom; the PDF you reference is an Australian publication. On the other hand, a web search for `"join chord" circle` yields a number of instances whose nationality isn't immediately obvious, so maybe this usage is more common than I was aware.

Comment: The screenshot also uses "produced" where I might use "extended". Maybe that's also an Australian thing, but I suspect both are "old Geometry language" things.

Comment: Thank you both very much. I'm so glad I have discovered this website. It's so good to get different perspectives and make sure that I am not going crazy when I notice these small things. As an Australian myself, it makes as much sense to me as it does to both of you, lol. I'm going to go with the idea that it is old geometry language. Thank you again :)